# Android custom map with custom image

Tags: android, android-mapview, android-maps

I want to code a map application in Android(MinSDK=2.1).

- But this map will not use any online features.It will be completely offline.
- Also this map shows a high definition image which is drawn by me.I must specify points (like buildings,parkings,cafes...etc) and place little Imageviews on these points.
- When needed , screen must move any requested point.

So Is there any sdk,library...etc to do this you know ? Or Should I implement myself.Lead the way pls.Thanks for any help...